# Emissions not working properly with alpha blending mode

Tags: shaders, transparency, shader-nodes, emission

I'm having some trouble getting this emission to work properly. I seem to have everything set up properly, but the emission is only glowing on certain points, as seen below:

[image: render example]

I also have the PNG I’m using as the texture:

[image: image texture]

Comment: At first sight, this tree is a bit confusing.. can you show us a bit of the .png texture?

Comment: There i added it

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use both the Principled shader's Alpha input AND then mix it to a transparent shader. You are doing the same operation twice, one is enough.

If all you need from your material is Emission and Transparency, then you don't need a Principled shader in the first place. Replace it by an Emission shader mixed into a transparency shader, with your texture's alpha as factor.

If you need more things like specular, SSS or whatever, then use a Principled alone with your texture's alpha plugged into the Principled's Alpha socket.

As far as the Glow effect is concerned: it could be multiple things. The biggest culprit I can think of would be the texture file itself. A highly compressed picture file with lots of unwanted blocking and value shifts can lead to such issues.

Comment: I think the poster is talking about the artefacts caused by the Bloom effect, like this: https://zupimages.net/up/23/06/xole.jpg

Comment: @moonboots I think so, too.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought too, but I can get a similar result by generating a BW grid, saving it into a loosely compressed JPEG and then turning that into a transparentcy PNG. You can easily get similar looking files from poor sources on the Internet, and it's the variation of values introduced by the compression that brings the variations in bloom even if they might not be visible in the texture itself. But @GordonBrinkmann's answer sounds as good too.

Answer (score 1):

The problems with the *Bloom* effect are most likely caused by those thin 1 pixel wide lines in your texture (or how wide they appear in the viewport)... the antialiasing effects result in slight variations of the intensity, then multiplied with an *Emission Strength* of almost 500 this results in brightness fluctuations which become visible in the bloom.

I cannot see your *Bloom* settings like *Threshold* etc., but let's say the intensity of the glow varies just between 0.7 and 1 - multiplied by 500 this is 350 and 500, the smaller the greater the gap. Depending on the threshold this can make quite a difference in bloom effect.

The glowing line itself will always be bright green or (if red and blue channels are > 0) get close to or reach white. But the image cannot have more than a value of 1 per channel, so the emission color might not show subtle differences, but they might affect the bloom.

Oh, and as @L0Lock says: when you use a *Principled BSDF* shader there is no need to mix with a *Transparent BSDF* shader.